# How do I add joins with selects in CodeIgniter/ActiveRecord?

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I want to add this part to my current sql in Active-Recod-class:

```
JOIN 
(SELECT product_id, max(angle) AS max_angle
FROM image t1
WHERE width = 100 AND height = 200
GROUP BY product_id) AS t1 ON (t1.product_id = mv_products.id)
```

What would be the correct approach to manage this?

Is the only way to download subquery-class github? https://github.com/NTICompass/CodeIgniter-Subqueries

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the kind of thing that you shouldn't do via CI's Active Record (Query Builder). It's there to help you with simple queries, not to force you to use it.

This is a custom query as such, should be executed via `$this->db->query()`.

With the currently released versions of CI, you wouldn't be able to do that via AR anyway because `join()` will break that subquery while trying to escape it (it assumes that you're only passing two field names). CI 3.0-dev allows you to disable field name escaping, but again - you shouldn't use the query builder for what you're asking here.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for input! My issue is that a LOT of other sql-statements are written with CI'S Active Record and as I understand there are no options to mix custom queries with CI's Active Record. I don't want to retype the whole query (long query based on filters category etc). Anyway I figured out a total different way to solve my problem, but I will give you heads up for your answer because it is very relevant!